# Docker run via ssh Connection reset by port 22

Tags: docker, ssh, raspberry-pi

a quick summary of the problem I'm facing: 
I am trying to connect via SSH to my raspberry pi, and then run a docker image on the raspberry pi.

I am able to connect via SSH to my raspberry pi. Once connected however, the Docker command resets the connection. Since the image is not stored locally, the first step is to pull the layers. In this step the Raspberry resets the connection on port 22, and I cant seem to understand why.

I've looked at quite a couple of online questions, and all of them seem to have the problem of connection reset already when trying to connect via SSH.

```
docker run \
    -d \
    --rm \
    -v /home/pi/Docker:/home/node/.mozilla-iot \
    --net=host \
    --name mozilla-iot-gateway \
    mozillaiot/gateway:arm
```

This is the output I get:

```
Unable to find image 'mozillaiot/gateway:arm' locally  
arm: Pulling from mozillaiot/gateway  
773085009f9c: Pulling fs layer  
15973945ecf5: Pulling fs layer  
4e25b539801e: Pulling fs layer  
a84cdb78f6b0: Waiting  
0c9b8944dc77: Waiting  
e5d5b177fb91: Waiting  
b607d4912e2c: Waiting  
f0483e81618e: Waiting  
a1e85dbd8e2c: Waiting  
e01229de56d3: Waiting  
9dd67d3b7895: Waiting  
e983d85a8d9c: Waiting  
00e328c139d4: Waiting  
7ae91a156a8c: Waiting  
Connection reset by 192.168.X.ZZZ port 22.
```

I'd expect the connection to not be reset, but instead pull the fs layer completely.

Does anyone have any idea why the connection might be reset? I tried exposing port 22, to no avail. Other than that, I simply have no idea where to start.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try to configure Docker daemon with --max-concurrent-downloads=1. Maybe default 3 concurrent downloads are killing your network connectivity to/from Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @JanGaraj Thanks for the attempt.  However, running sudo dockerd --max-concurrent-downloads=1 results in Connection reset by 192.168.X.ZZZ port 22, so in the same error. I am trying it on a different network right now, so it seems like a very fundament problem with docker right now. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like a problem with slow network/cpu. Are you able to download 700 MB file over https in that Raspberry without any issue (that is an equivalent of your docker pull request).

Comment: @JanGaraj Yes I can do that

Comment: I just hooked my raspberry pi to a monitor. Running docker run hello-world does what it's supposed to --- pulls the image if not stored locally, and runs it. However, docker pull mozillaiot/gateway:arm (and without :arm) reboots the pi. So the connection closed because it was rebooting - still, I don't understand why that is happening. Any ideas?